# CSS3 Automatic Word Hyphenation works on FireFox, not on Internet Explorer and Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, hyphenation

According to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fhyphens#Languages_support_notes) not only FireFox but *also* Internet Explorer should support the use of automatic hyphenation in css/html, however my demo (using the Dutch language, which *is* supported by IE).

> [**SEE MY CSS DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/41bakfpe/1/) where hyphenation *does* work flawlessly on FF 42 but not on current IE 11 while it should be supported. What am I doing wrong? Below the css and html i'm using.

```
article p{
    -webkit-hyphens : auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
}

<article lang="nl">
<p>........</P>
</article>
```

What am I doing wrong? What part of this css code needs to be changed sothat auto hyphenation works on Internet Explorer as well on the Dutch (nl) language?

Comment: I assume you have the `Dutch (Netherlands)` language pack installed? See Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem until I used `lang="en"` inside the `<html>` tag, so setting your `lang` attribute will allow these browsers to actually hyphenate with your language.